# problem installing rails3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, rvm

Tried the link
http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm

---

```
gokul@gokul-laptop:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [i486-linux]
gokul@gokul-laptop:~$ mkdir -p ~/.rvm/src/ && cd ~/.rvm/src && rm -rf ./rvm/ && git clone git://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm.git && cd rvm && ./install

The program 'git' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:

sudo apt-get install git-core
git: command not found

gokul@gokul-laptop:~/.rvm/src$ sudo apt-get install git-core
[sudo] password for gokul: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

gokul@gokul-laptop:~/.rvm/src$
```

---

anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last error message (`E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?`) means that there's an other process that's been locking aptitude.

You can't install any new package until aptitude remains locked.
Is there Synaptic started ? If so, you should close it. Are you installing any other package in the same time ?
You should wait for the other installation to have stopped before to be able to install git.